# css fix white space appearing after image

Tags: html, css

I have tried all the option that were know to me. Please help me in removing the white space between image and the div tag. I don't know why white is appearing below the image and div. I can not figure out where the CSS'm wrong. I have been working on it since morning but I am not able to find the solution this.

Please help me. I have uploaded the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwnGT.jpg).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rent-O-Roof</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body{
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      }
      .topnav{
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      }
      .topnav a{
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
      }
      .topnav a:hover{
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
      }
      .active{
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      }
      .topnav .icon{
      display: none;
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 600px){
      .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
      .topnav a.icon {
      float: right;
      display: block;
      }
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 600px){
      .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
      .topnav.responsive .icon {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      }
      .topnav.responsive a{
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
      }
      }
      /* Style the footer */
      .footer {
      background-color:#777555 ;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="#aboutus">About US</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact US</a>
      <a href="#about">google form</a>
      <a href="#about">facebook page</a>
      <a href="#about">CUSTOMER REVIEW</a>
      <a href="#about">CAREERS</a>
      <a href="#about">TERM</a>
      <a href="#about">OPTIONS</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
          var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
          if (x.className === "topnav") {
              x.className += " responsive";
          } else {
              x.className = "topnav";
          }
      }
    </script>
    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
      <img src="file:///Users/varunwadhwa/Desktop/Header.png" style="width: 100%; height: auto; overflow: hidden; padding: 0;">
      <div style="background-color: red; font-size: 48px;">About Us
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Without running your code, I'm willing to bet that if you remove the actual space (newline + spaces) between your `img` and `div`, the problem will disappear.  You can get around this with CSS by setting `font-size: 0` or using a different display layout.

Comment: thank yo sir helping me sir @Scott

Answer (score 0):

It is space for descenders (the bits that hang off the bottom of 'y' and 'p') since img is an inline element by default. This attribute removes the gap.

Just add `display: block` to your img style.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdvxjkxy/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rent-O-Roof</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body{
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      }
      .topnav{
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      }
      .topnav a{
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
      }
      .topnav a:hover{
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
      }
      .active{
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      }
      .topnav .icon{
      display: none;
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 600px){
      .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
      .topnav a.icon {
      float: right;
      display: block;
      }
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 600px){
      .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
      .topnav.responsive .icon {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      }
      .topnav.responsive a{
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
      }
      }
      /* Style the footer */
      .footer {
      background-color:#777555 ;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="#aboutus">About US</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact US</a>
      <a href="#about">google form</a>
      <a href="#about">facebook page</a>
      <a href="#about">CUSTOMER REVIEW</a>
      <a href="#about">CAREERS</a>
      <a href="#about">TERM</a>
      <a href="#about">OPTIONS</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
          var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
          if (x.className === "topnav") {
              x.className += " responsive";
          } else {
              x.className = "topnav";
          }
      }
    </script>
    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" style="width: 100%; height: 150px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0; display: block;">
      <div style="background-color: red; font-size: 48px;">About Us
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank yo sir helping me sir @Zhenya Telegin

Comment: sir can you please explain the cause of the problem thank you sir @Zhenya Telegin

Comment: It is space for descenders (the bits that hang off the bottom of 'y' and 'p') since `img` is an inline element by default. This attribute removes the gap. Please upvote if I helped :)

Comment: yes sir it worked for me. thank you sir helping me @ Zhenya Telegin

Answer (score 0):

add `display: block` to the img tag like Zhenya Telegin said or give the "about" div a negative margin-top value, something like `margin-top: -4px`

Comment: thank yo sir helping me sir @FutoRicky

Comment: sir can you please explain the cause of the problem thank you sir @FutoRicky